# http.ReadRequest does not parse body of POST Request from file

Tags: go

**request.txt**

```
POST /login HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
Accept: */*

pass=112233
```

**CODE**

```
req, err := ioutil.ReadFile("./request.txt")

if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

reqbuf := bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader(string(req)))

myreq, err := http.ReadRequest(reqbuf)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(myreq.Body)
fmt.Println(myreq.Host)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{}
example.com
```

Why body is empty? How can I parse full POST request (including body of request) from file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The requests is incomplete. It is missing a [Content-length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.2) header which covers the body. Without this it is assumed that the body is empty. In your specific example adding `Content-length: 10` to the request header does the job.